# Where do values from unintialized variables come from?

Tags: c++, variables, garbage

When you declare a local variable i like so :

```
int i;
```

And you use this variable, you will get undefined behaviour because i isn't initialized yet. But i holds a value, a "garbage" value, where does this value come from?  is it from a random place in memory?

Comment: The variable usually has a location in memory, in which case its value would be whatever happens to be in that memory location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't know, you can't tell. Undefined behavior means that anything can happen.

That said, in practice on most implementations and most of the time `int i;` will reserve `sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack (which is usually *somewhere* in main memory), so the value of `i` will be whatever happens to be on the stack at this moment.

But don't rely on it, and remember that this isn't always true.

Answer (score 2):

Its whatever was in memory at &i before.